# Steam Dynamic Collection with and/or logic in tags

Tags: steam

Is it possible to create a Dynamic Library in Steam, that uses "OR" logic?
E.g. all games that have either tag "A" OR tag "B"?

If you add multiple tags to a search, it uses "AND" logic.
I've noticed that you can manually add games to a saved dynamic library, which acts as a "OR" logic (it shows all games which either that tag OR the manually added games).

If it is not possible to do this manually in the Steam GUI, would there be a way to do this programmatically with the Steam API?